# Can we create a token with some data inside it?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, chaindata

I wane to write some data (like a link to some file etc) in a token, and once someone sends it from one address to another, that data should be sent as well. Is there anyway we can do now? or you this its not feasible?

Thanks,

Comment: could you be more specific? what kind of token?

Comment: I have erc20 token, and Im going to open an ICO for them. Once we are done. I would like to allow the people to send their tokens to anyone, and when they transfer they can add some information (like some links) and when someone get it, they can see that link.

Comment: ok, so you have an answer from @shane about ERC20

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with ERC721 tokens and is built into to spec itself in the form if metadata.

You cannot do this with ERC20 tokens, as there is no way to differentiate between individual tokens during a transaction.

Comment: Yes. This metadata concept is intended for this purpose and it is intended to be used heavily.

Comment: thanks, since I have already created the erc-20 token and my partners are willing to use it, is there a way we can just send some information during our tokens transfer? and it can be read on etherscan? It is not mandatory to link that message specific to a token.